# Calling custom dynamic Blocks in transactional emails

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, transactional

in my transactional email page i've used this

```
{{block type='sales/dispatch' area='frontend' template='email/order/dispatch.phtml' order=$order shipment=$shipment}}
```

my block is under sales module which is like this

```
class Mypackage_Sales_Block_Dispatch extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {

        public function checkinout(){

            return 'testingg......';
        }
}
```

and my dispatch.phtml file looks like this

```
echo $this->checkinout();
```

but in the email i'm not getting this block printed, what am i doing wrong? thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `<sales>` as a node in `config.xml`, this name is already used by `Mage_Sales`.

Rename your node and you are one step further.